# Error using .pop() function to take user input to replace a certain point in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Giving a TypeError and not sure why, want the inputted index to delete a spot in the list:

```py
      x = input('Which part of the list would you like to remove?(index starts at 0):')

      myThing.pop()[x]

      print(myThing)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = input('Which part of the list would you like to remove?(index starts at 0):')

myThing.pop(int(x))
print(myThing)
```

pop takes the index you want to remove as an argument, so you pass it in the parenthesis following the `.pop`. Also, you need to convert your input to an `int`, as `input()` return a `str`

Comment: @MaxPaul, if this helped solve your problem please mark it as the accepted answer with the green check on the left.